# Question about calling subprogram in main-program structure?

Tags: fortran

A routine approach for calling subprogram in the main-program structure is writing them in the same executable file and run the main program. Some tools (such as modules) are existed for this approach.

My question is about when there are too many subprograms and they are located in separate executable files. Also about when there are too many subprograms but they are in on executable file as "module".

How we can call them in main-program structure and comparison between program execution times.

I also read this: [how to link main and subprograms in Fortran95?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469362/how-to-link-main-and-subprograms-in-fortran95)
But it did not help enough. Please, answer my question simplest form and comprehensively as possible because I'm new to fortran.

The code and subcode would execute in PLATO as the compiler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [performance of internal function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405779/performance-of-internal-function)

Comment: @jack Nope. My Question about: 1) whole parts in one executable file and 2) mainparts in one executable file and subparts in separates executable files 3) mainparts in one executable file and subparts in one executable file with "MODULE".

Comment: As stated in the linked answer: "'ll go further, I don't believe that there is very much in the language's standard (any of them) that gives good support for arguments about the relative performance of variant approaches to implementing the same functionality." W.r.t your question: Following Fortran standard there shouldnt be any performance differences but compiler implementation might lead to differences.

Comment: @jack If we supposed your link is related to the second part (" comparison between program execution times") of my question what about the first part ("How we can call them in main-program structure").

Comment: I'm afraid the question (if I understand it) is unanswerable - it will depend at the very least on your hardware, your compiler, how the code is compiled, how the code is linked, your operating system and any libraries you use. It will vary from platform to platform. First and foremost write your code so it is understandable and manageable - what you want to minimise is the total cost of ownership, which is not just run time, but also includes development, maintenance and debugging as well.

Comment: Are you confusing source code files and executables?   If you have a complicated Fortran program, it would by typical to place subprograms in modules in one or more separate files from the main program.   The combination of the compiler and linker would merge these into a single executable.   If you have the same subprogram/module structure, it would be surprising for the executable performance to depend on whether you used one or several source code files.  Also, PLATO seems to be an IDE that invokes the Silverfrost Fortran compiler.